# Google cloud Platform(GCP) Unknown error. Original error message: Operation failed: Insufficient CPU quota in region

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql, quota

I want to create a VPC connector to connect the App engine to the cloud SQL instance. As the connector should be in the same region as the SQL instance is, I have selected the same region. But after creating the VPC connector it gives me an error:
`Unknown error. Original error message: Operation failed: Insufficient CPU quota in region.`

I tell you that I am using a free Tier GCP account. Is this problem is from my side? related to my account? How to resolve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Each project has an 8 CPU quota limit, not related to projects. 8 CPU quota limit in a region. Every deployment of serverless VPC is using 8 CPUs. So, I use 1 vCPU instance for scaling like F1 micro for Serverless VPC connector.

Answer (score 5):

Accordingly  to the error message, you don't have enough CPU in the region. This resource usage is limited by [quota](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota).

Unfortunately, *you won't be able to increase this quota while using* [90-day, $300 Free Trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier/#free-trial). Have a look at the documentation:

> **Program coverage**:
>
> - You can't request a quota increase. For an overview of Compute Engine quotas, see [Resource quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas).

**To solve this issue** and increase quota, you can upgrade to a [paid Cloud Billing account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier/#how-to-upgrade).

Comment: Thanks, So, is there any other way to resolve this issue in the free trial account? Is this error region-specific, as the error suggests an Insufficient CPU quota in the region. But, I cannot change the location of the project.

Comment: I doubt that there's any way to solve without upgrading to paid billing account.